# yyyy/mm/dd format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, format

I have a `date` column in SQL Server and I want to get date in `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

My code is:

```
select
    convert(date, Consumption_FDate, 111)
from  
    dbo.TblStuff_Consumption
```

`Consumption_FDate` is my `date` column and `dbo.TblStuff_Consumption` is my table.

My problem is this code is not working; the output is same every time, though I change '111' into other numbers.

Comment: This belongs in the presentation layer not in the sql code.

Comment: Yes - because you're converting **to a `DATE`** which will then be displayed using the **default settings** in SQL Server. If you want to enforce a specific format, you need to convert **to a `VARCHAR(n)` ! (where `n` should be large enough to hold your date including any special characters - at least 10 characters long)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Consumption_FDate, 111)
FROM dbo.TblStuff_Consumption
```

Answer (score -3):

In SQL serve 8 working fine

select convert(varchar,getDate(),112)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score -3):

CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())    output `Nov 04 2014 11:45 PM`
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10) output `11-04-14`
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) output `11-04-2014`
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6) output `04 Nov 14`
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106) output`04 Nov 2014`
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113) output`04 Nov 2014 11:45:34:24`